# Что значит "собирать api через composer"?

Tags: php, api, composer, backend

Можете объяснить, что значит собирать api через composer?
Делаю тестовое задание, api реализовал через htaccess, и меня спросили, как я собирал api, через composer?

Answer (score 1):

Composer в php - это менеджер зависимостей. Это что-то на подобии npm в js (если знакомы). Для чего это нужно? Для того, чтобы при разворачивании проекта не копировать тонны сторонних библиотек, а запустить одну команду, и composer сам подтянет все зависимости необходимых версий.

Подробнее можете ознакомиться [здесь](https://getcomposer.org/)